# how to do select all when selected a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i have a table where i am filling some data and have checkboxes besides each and the last check box is "ALL".
When i check this "ALL" checkbox remaining check boxes should be checked and vice versa.

code for filling data.

```
<div class="tablecontatiner">

<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Function</th>
                    <th>Add</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <th>All</th>
                    </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr class="grouprow">
                    <td><input type="hidden"/><input id="@(item.Func_Code)" type="checkbox"  style="visibility:hidden" />@item.FunctionName</td>
                    <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "A")" type="checkbox" value="Add" @(item.Add==true?"checked":"") /></td>
                    <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "E")" type="checkbox" value="Edit" @(item.Edit==true?"checked":"") /></td>
                    <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "V")" type="checkbox" value="View" @(item.View==true?"checked":"")/></td>
                    <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "D")" type="checkbox" value="Delete" @(item.Delete==true?"checked":"")/></td>
                    <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "ALL")" type="checkbox" value="All"/></td>
                    </tr>
                }
 </table>
</div>
```

and my UI looks like [image: this]:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#checkboxAll').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('.grouprow').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
$('table tr input:checkbox:not("#checkboxAll")').on('change', function () {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $('#checkboxAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5axwU/14/)

Comment: what is #chekcboxAll her...id of that checkbox? or Value or checkbox?

Comment: Id of the checkbox that is supposed to check/uncheck all

Comment: tried your demo...but didn't work for when i unchecked any one checkbox.the all checkbox should be unchecked

Comment: and one more case...when user checks all the checkboxes,the "All" checkbox should be checked.

Comment: @Santosh http://jsfiddle.net/5axwU/15/ If you got another question create a new question.

Comment: worked for new case(when user checks all the checkboxes,the "All" checkbox should be checked.)but failing in some cases..while unchecking

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //listen to the change of checkbox in the last td
    $('.tablecontatiner td:last-child input').on('change', function () {
        //update the checked property of all checkboxes in the same row as the changed checkbox
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

$('#chkAll').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.grouprow').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});

Answer (score 0):

Anton's solution is very elegant.
If you load (or reload) the table and don't want to set the event handlers each time it is reloaded, then I would change a bit the solution:

```
$('.tablecontatiner').on('change', '[id$=All]', function () {
    $(this).closest('.grouprow').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**Remark**: Also I would give "checkboxAll" class to each "*ALL*" checkbox, so it will look like:

```
<input id="@(item.Func_Code + "ALL")" type="checkbox" value="All" class="checkboxAll"/>
```

and then the code above will be:

```
$('.tablecontatiner').on('change', '.checkboxAll', function () {
    $(this).closest('.grouprow').find('input').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/jetewayi/1/edit

Comment: what about when a checkbox is unchecked? The "All" checkbox should be unchecked at that time

Comment: Of course, if you change it it changes just because you change it. So you shouldn't do anything more with the "All" checkbox. That's why not(this) filter is applied. Try the jsbin example I've added to my answer.