# How to use checkall when checked one checkbox in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a table that has five checkboxes(Add, Edit, View, Delete, All).
These table rows are generated dynamically.
Code for that is as follows:

```
<div class="tablecontatiner">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Function</th>
            <th>Add</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>View</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>All</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr class="grouprow">
            <td><input type="hidden"/><input id="@(item.Func_Code)" type="checkbox"  style="visibility:hidden" />@item.FunctionName</td>
            <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "A")" type="checkbox" value="Add" @(item.Add==true?"checked":"") /></td>
            <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "E")" type="checkbox" value="Edit" @(item.Edit==true?"checked":"") /></td>
            <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "V")" type="checkbox" value="View" @(item.View==true?"checked":"")/></td>
            <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "D")" type="checkbox" value="Delete" @(item.Delete==true?"checked":"")/></td>
            <td><input id="@(item.Func_Code + "ALL")" type="checkbox" value="All"/></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to work around my last checkbox(All).  My requirement is that when I check that "All" checkbox, the remaining checkboxes should be checked and when I uncheck "All" checkbox, the remaining checkboxes should be unchecked.

I am using following Jquery for this.

```
<script>
$('.CheckAll').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('.grouprow').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
$('table tr input:checkbox:not(".CheckAll")').on('change', function () {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $('.CheckAll').prop('checked', false);
    }

    //var checkedBoxes = $(this).closest('.grouprow').find('input:checkbox:not(".CheckAll"):checked');
    //if (checkedBoxes.length == 4) {
    //    $('.CheckAll').prop('checked', true);
    //}
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine, but when I uncheck any one of the checkbox in any row when all the remaining rows checkboxes are checked, the "All" checkbox for all the rows is unchecked.
Any help?

Comment: how is it different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146610/how-to-do-select-all-when-selected-a-checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the code like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.CheckAll').on('change', function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $('table tr input:checkbox:not(".CheckAll")').on('change', function () {

            if (!this.checked) {
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.CheckAll').prop('checked', false);
            }

        });
    });
```

Because you are unchecking all the chackboxes that have the class "CheckAll". This code will uncheck only the closest checkbox.

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QdGzt/)

updated [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QdGzt/1/)

Comment: no,its not working.i modified the code.The uncheck is not working(When i unchecked any one checkbox in a particular row,the "All" checkbox in that row is not unchecked).

Comment: ..Thanks buddy,it worked.But one case is still missing here.When i check all the checkboxes(one by one) in a particular row,the "All" checkbox for that row should be checked.

Comment: @Santosh can you create a fiddle for that? then i can help you

Comment: Can you please check the jsfiddle(in the above comment)

Comment: tried the updated fiddle..but couldnt understand about hidden checkbox.And also the when i check the first checkbox(which is under Function) only the "All" checkbox is checked.In my case i dont have any checkbox under "Function".i can check "Add","Edit","View","Delete" .is this purposeful change from your side?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check for the length:

```
if ($('.grouprow').find(':checked').length != $('.grouprow').find(':checkbox').length) {
    $('.CheckAll').prop('checked', false);
}
```